# Как с помощью нажатия по div менять его класс

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на блок один раз - меняет цвет или форму (из состояния 1 в состояние 2). При нажатии второй раз - меняет размер (из состояния 2 в состояние 3). Третий раз возвращает в исходное положение (из состояния 3 в состояние 1).

```css
.class1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.class2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.class3{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения классов у элемента, необходимо повесить обработчик клика на элемент `addEventListener('click', () => {})`. Так же зададим элементу ID, что бы выбрать его селектором.

В обработчике будем проверять очередность клика и удалять предыдущий класс, и добавлять новый. Для удобства и создания необходимой последовательности, создадим массивов классов с их наименованием.

```js
  // Селектором выбираем элемент. 
  const elem = document.getElementById('classChange');
  // Создаем массив классов для ротации
  const classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];
  // Текущий номер класса(номер элемента массива) 
  let i = 0;
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Записываем предыдущее значение
      const prev = i;
      // Текущее увеличиваем на 1
      i++;
      // Если выходим за границы массива, устанавливаем первый элемент
      if (i >= classes.length) {
          i = 0;
      }
      // Удаляем предыдущий класс
      elem.classList.remove(classes[prev]);
      // Добавляем текущий класс
      elem.classList.add(classes[i]);
  })
```

```css
.class1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.class2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.class3{
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!-- Добавили ID classChange элементу -->
<div id="classChange" class="class1"></div>
```